# jQuery making images bigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my site I've got images which are in reality for example 2000 / 1500 px

I resized them using width and height properties in CSS, but I would like to show them bigger (maybe in popup or something like that) after clicking on them.

Which one plugin or method is the easiest one to accomplish this?

Comment: An aside: you should try not to use CSS to resize images to the page.  It slows your page download times, as the browser needs to download all the 2000px images right away and then resize them on the fly.  Better to create thumbnails.

Comment: If you are using rails check out paperclip.

Comment: ok create thumbnails and then after clicking showing in popup big image. Sounds great, do You know any plugin which can be used ?

Answer (score 4):

```js
$('img').click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

```css
img {
    width: 50px;
    height: auto;
}

.clicked {
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" /> <img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" /> <img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" /> <img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" /> <img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" /> <img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />  <img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />
```

Comment: much easier to use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) `$(this).toggleClass('clicked');`

Answer (score 1):

Fancybox (jQuery plugin) is one of my favorites: http://fancybox.net/

Very easy to use and the site provides a lot of examples.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any specific plugin for that. You can simply use jQuery's `css` method:

```
$('img').css({
    width: 'auto',
    height: 'auto'
});
```

**Note:** This'll target all of your images. You'll want to replace that with your own CSS selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can find many of them [out there](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20lightbox&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)
All of them extremely easy to implement.